# retornar datos JSON de funcion anonima para fullcalendar no renderiza

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, fullcalendar

Estoy trabajando con full calendar y jquery.
intentando obtener los eventos para desplegarlos en fullcalendar del mismo nodo donde se va a inicializar, la idea es poder leer de el mismo los datos en un atributo: `data-cal`

hasta la lectura todo va bien pero fullcalendar no pinta los eventos que se le dan en formato JSON:

```js
var allcalendars = $('.calendar-event');
allcalendars.each(function() {
  var target = $(this);
  target.fullCalendar({
    height: '725px',
    locale: 'es',
    events: function(event, xhr, settings) {
      var eventos = target.attr("data-cal");
      console.log(eventos);
      eventos = eventos.replace(/'/g, '"');
      eventos = JSON.parse(eventos);
      console.log(eventos);
      return eventos;
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.10.2/fullcalendar.min.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="calendar-event" data-cal="[{'id':'1','resourceId':'a','title':'ORT0000001','start':'2021-05-20','color':'green'},{'id':'2','resourceId':'a','title':'ORT0000002','start':'2021-05-20','color':'green'},{'id':'3','resourceId':'a','title':'ORT0000003','start':'2021-05-20','color':'gray'},{'id':'4','resourceId':'a','title':'ORT0000004','start':'2021-05-21','color':'orange'},{'id':'5','resourceId':'a','title':'CONT0000158','start':'2021-05-23','color':'blue'},{'id':'6','resourceId':'a','title':'CONT0000159','start':'2021-05-25','color':'blue'},{'id':'7','resourceId':'a','title':'CONT0000159','start':'2021-05-25','color':'gray'}]"></div>
  </body>


  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.10.2/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.10.2/locale/es.min.js"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problemas**

1. La funcion anonima de `events`, no recibe esos parametros `event, xhr, settings`(Supongo que esto lo sacastes de Ajax), sino `start, end, timezone, callback` como dice la [documentacion](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/events-function)
2. No te retorna los eventos con `return` porque debes utlizar la funcion `callback`, ya que en la documentacion dice(en español):

> Se debe llamar cuando la función de evento personalizado haya generado sus eventos. Es responsabilidad de la función de evento asegurarse de que callbackse llame con una matriz de objetos de evento

**Soluciones**

Tienes 2 posibles soluciones a esto ya que simplemente podrias `rotornar la matriz` sin usar la funcion anonima o utilizar la `funcion anonima` y usar `callback`

1. Retornar solo la matriz

```js
var allcalendars = $('.calendar-event');
allcalendars.each(function() {
  var target = $(this);
  target.fullCalendar({
    height: '725px',
    locale: 'es',
    events: JSON.parse((target.attr("data-cal")).replace(/'/g, '"'))
  });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.10.2/fullcalendar.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="calendar-event" data-cal="[{'id':'1','resourceId':'a','title':'ORT0000001','start':'2021-05-20','color':'green'},{'id':'2','resourceId':'a','title':'ORT0000002','start':'2021-05-20','color':'green'},{'id':'3','resourceId':'a','title':'ORT0000003','start':'2021-05-20','color':'gray'},{'id':'4','resourceId':'a','title':'ORT0000004','start':'2021-05-21','color':'orange'},{'id':'5','resourceId':'a','title':'CONT0000158','start':'2021-05-23','color':'blue'},{'id':'6','resourceId':'a','title':'CONT0000159','start':'2021-05-25','color':'blue'},{'id':'7','resourceId':'a','title':'CONT0000159','start':'2021-05-25','color':'gray'}]"></div>
</body>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.10.2/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.10.2/locale/es.min.js"></script>

</html>
```

2. Utilizar la funcion anonima

```js
var allcalendars = $('.calendar-event');
allcalendars.each(function() {
  var target = $(this);
  target.fullCalendar({
    height: '725px',
    locale: 'es',
    events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
      var eventos = target.attr("data-cal");
      eventos = eventos.replace(/'/g, '"');
      eventos = JSON.parse(eventos);
      callback(eventos);
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.10.2/fullcalendar.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="calendar-event" data-cal="[{'id':'1','resourceId':'a','title':'ORT0000001','start':'2021-05-20','color':'green'},{'id':'2','resourceId':'a','title':'ORT0000002','start':'2021-05-20','color':'green'},{'id':'3','resourceId':'a','title':'ORT0000003','start':'2021-05-20','color':'gray'},{'id':'4','resourceId':'a','title':'ORT0000004','start':'2021-05-21','color':'orange'},{'id':'5','resourceId':'a','title':'CONT0000158','start':'2021-05-23','color':'blue'},{'id':'6','resourceId':'a','title':'CONT0000159','start':'2021-05-25','color':'blue'},{'id':'7','resourceId':'a','title':'CONT0000159','start':'2021-05-25','color':'gray'}]"></div>
</body>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.10.2/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.10.2/locale/es.min.js"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para poder obtener la instacia, existe un método concreto getCalendar.

```js
//--> https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/methods

;(($)=>{
  $(function(){
    let allCalendars = $('.calendar-event');    
    allCalendars.each((i,v)=>{
      let strData = $(v).data('cal').replace(/'/g, '"');
      let data = JSON.parse(strData);
      $(v).fullCalendar({ locale: 'es' }); 
      var calendar = $(v).fullCalendar('getCalendar');
      calendar.addEventSource(data);
    });
  })
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.10.2/fullcalendar.min.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="calendar-event" data-cal="[{'id':'1','resourceId':'a','title':'ORT0000001','start':'2021-05-20','color':'green'},{'id':'2','resourceId':'a','title':'ORT0000002','start':'2021-05-20','color':'green'},{'id':'3','resourceId':'a','title':'ORT0000003','start':'2021-05-20','color':'gray'},{'id':'4','resourceId':'a','title':'ORT0000004','start':'2021-05-21','color':'orange'},{'id':'5','resourceId':'a','title':'CONT0000158','start':'2021-05-23','color':'blue'},{'id':'6','resourceId':'a','title':'CONT0000159','start':'2021-05-25','color':'blue'},{'id':'7','resourceId':'a','title':'CONT0000159','start':'2021-05-25','color':'gray'}]"></div>
  </body>


  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.10.2/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.10.2/locale/es.min.js"></script>

</html>
```